# How do I add a "new window" entry to the nautilus quicklist?

Tags: unity, nautilus, quicklists

When I right click on 'file manager' in the launcher I can select 'home folder', but it takes an open nautilus window and displays the home folder in that window, often shunting me back to a different workspace.

How can I open a new nautilus window from the launcher?

Comment: You want to make it so you can select "new window" and NOT have it move to another workspace right?

Comment: Or, to open a new window on current workspace .. instead of jumping to open instance elsewhere?

Comment: This functionality will be present by default in 12.04 LTS once it releases, and has already been added: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/nautilus-quicklist-adds-bookmark-support-for-precise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the middle mouse button to click the Home Folder. This will launch a new window of Nautilus.